# Why should I use 'i in array' inside my own custom 'array.indexOf'?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I have seen many times things like this:

```
function customArrayIndexOf(item, array){
    for (var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (i in array && array[i] === item) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

However, I am not sure why is the `i in array` needed.

**I have three questions:**

- What it is doing?
- Is it necessary?
- When it will fail without it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sparse arrays may cause a false positive without the check:

```
var customArrayIndexOf = function(item, array){
    for (var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (i in array && array[i] === item) return i;
    }
    return -1;
},
customArrayIndexOfNoCheck = function(item, array){
    for (var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (array[i] === item) return i;
    }
    return -1;
};

var t=[]; t[1]=1;

customArrayIndexOfNoCheck(undefined, t); // 0
customArrayIndexOf(undefined, t); // -1
```

(`i` and `l` should be local, i.e. declared with `var`)

Comment: @mithril333221, no it isn't, try it yourself; the native implementation `var t=[];t[1]=1;t.indexOf(undefined);` returns `-1`. While `t[0]===undefined` that doesn't mean that there is an entry of undefined in the array, it just means that the native lookup function returned that value.

Comment: @davin okey, i will accept your answer. just a last thing, why it is `-1`?, edit: your edit answered this, so I guess there is no need for further aclarations